# CarouFredSel make pagination responsive

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, pagination, caroufredsel

I am looking into making my existing carousel responsive, I have pagination and it displays all the pages, however, it contains many pages, so when I try to fit it into a smaller screen, the numbers run into a second line. I also have next and back buttons.

What I want is be able to display, for example, numbers from 1 to 5 and three dots(...), then when click next in page 5, display 6 to 10 and so on. Each page will contain one item when viewed in the smaller screen, or possibly 2, one under the other.

Has anyone implemented something similar that can give me some sample code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an example that does something like this on their examples/ inspiration page. It's #38 - "Carousel with truncated pagination because of the large amount of items," which gives example code that allows you to determine the number of pages at start and end of the pagination range, as well as a number in the middle, with all between truncated. E.g. [1]...[4][5][6]...[15]

It does update as you navigate through (the example is autoplaying and continuously updating the pagination).

Find it here:
http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/38/